# Messed up with .bind() and .unbind() in jQuery

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, binding, jquery

Ok, so i have two ways to perform div refresh

```
$('#player').load('/videos/index');
```

in my rails app. One is through link

```
<a href="#" id="nextb" onclick="$('#player').load('/videos/index').unbind();">next</a>
```

other is through shortcut of that button. And they work fine, until i discovered, that if I refresh player twice in a row through the link, and then through the shortcut, it loads div twicely. If i refresh through the link three times in a row, than through the shortcut, than it's loading div three times. And so on..
So, i've started to trying configure binds (as I assumed, that was the reason), but there were mo result.
Here is my messed up in binds shortcut part of application.js

```
 $(document).ready(function(){;
$(document).bind('keydown', 'space', function() {
    $('#player').unbind('load');    
    $('#player').load('/videos/index');
    $(document).unbind();
    }); 
 });
```

I tried to click on link through the shortcut, but the same result, so I've assume, the problem is in load. Any suggestions would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid a double refresh, is having an state flag, indicating if it can load again, or if it's loading:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var loading = false;
    function reloadDiv() {
        if(!loading) {
            loading = true;
            $('#player').load('/videos/index', null, function() { loading = false; });
        }
    }  
    $('#nextb').click(reloadDiv);
    $(document).bind('keydown', 'space', reloadDiv);
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: Bad luck:/ @Gonzalo I've changed all the code from the post on your example, but now it's loading div twicely after any second in a row click on link or shortcut

Comment: have you removed the onclick property in #nextb?

Comment: add a console.log("reloading") behind the `load` call (inside the if). Check if it's being called twice, or if there's something else reloading the div. I'll edit the code. It's better to put `loading = true` before `$().load()` to avoid a race condition. Anyway it's not multithread, but it's more safe :-)

Comment: @Gonzalo, No changes. Console is showing nothing but `application.js:73reloading
2:3000/#:73reloading` and 73 is `console.log("reloading")` in my code

Comment: Then it's something else in your code. Look, you have only one call to `.load` in your code. If it's getting called twice, but reported only one time in the console, then you're loading it in other area of your code. If you want, paste it at pastebin.com or edit your questin and we can take a look. Good luck!

Comment: Yup, you are right, I've totally forgotten the .load in player's jquery plugin, it was there to load the next video after current will end. Thou, it is very strange, that it is so picky, that assuming, that video has ended after two link's and one shortcut's loads. Anyway, I don't feel, that I would be to manage that, so I've decided to leave only the shortcut. Thank you for your time!